# GitHub Actions - PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, phpunit, github-actions

I am trying to run my feature tests for a Laravel app on GitHub Actions. The tests run fine locally, but when the GitHub Actions fires I get a memory size error. How can I avoid this and run the tests successfully on GitHub Actions servers?

This is the github action YML file we have set up:

```
jobs:
  laravel-feature-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Feature tests

    steps:
    ...
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '7.3'
        extensions: gd, mysql
        tools: composer:v1
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-suggest --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Execute Feature tests via PHPUnit
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Feature
```

This is the failure in GitHub:

```
Run vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Feature
PHPUnit 6.0.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

................................................................  63 / 750 (  8%)
............................................................... 126 / 750 ( 16%)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in <project>/vendor/symfony/routing/RouteCompiler.php on line 188
```

What can we do to bypass this `Allowed memory size exhausted` error to run our tests with GitHub Actions?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why is this question tagged with [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: i thought it might have something to do with composer tasks. I'll remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

I had a memory limit setting in one of my controller routes that was being tested. Removing this line or doubling the memory limit allowed the tests to pass:

```
public function myRoute(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // <-- removing this line or setting to 2048M worked
```

Comment: Why do you have that line, and in a controller ? That is a no-no !